# SVM Hard margin: why imbalanced dataset may cause bad results?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, svm, libsvm

I can understand why soft Margin SVM are subject to imbalanced training set: minimizing the error of the optimiziation problem can drive to classify all data training to be negative (if  |negative examples| >> |positive examples| ).

But, in hard margin SVM, I haven't slack variables and C costant, so I don't want to minimize the error, because hard margin SVM expected no error (for the definition of the problem)! hard margin SVM just search the support vectors and maximize the margin between the classes support hyperplanes "identified" by the support vectors; now, if I have "behind" the negative support vectors (i.e. the negative class suppoort hyperplane) a lot of points or the same number of positive points, these do not affect my margin and separation hyperplane;

it's always the same since it depends just from support vector, and they are always the same regardless if I increase the number of points! why hard margin SVM are subject to imbalanced dataset or where my reasoning is wrong?
thanks!

Comment: You may review the concept of Granular SVM Under-sampling (GSVM-RU) which illustrates a solution based on the support vectors given data imbalance problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a true hard margin SVM there are two options for any data set, regardless of how its balanced:

1. The training data is *perfectly* separable in feature space, you get a resulting model with 0 training errors.
2. The training data is *not* separable in feature space, you will not get anything (no model).

Additionally, take note that you could train hard margin SVM on any data set given a kernel that is complex enough (RBF with very large gamma, for instance). The resulting model is generally bad, though, as it is a total overfit of the training data.